# lftp show remote recursive directory size

Tags: python-2.7, lftp

I've been using smartftp (windows only )to work out the file size of remote directories before downloading them. I've switched over to ubuntu and ive been looking around but I don't see if lftp has this feature or maybe someone can show me a way to do this via cli or maybe with a python script

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

looks like lftp supports regular linux commands. incase anyone else runs into this just do a du -h

Comment: Note that wildcards should be used with `glob` as, for example from the lftp shell: `glob -a du -sh *` where `-a` applies the glob to any kind of file (files and directories). See the man page.